# gradle-resources-production:mymod.main: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 75

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft-fabric

```java
gradle-resources-production:mymod.main: 
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 75:
 C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2\jbr\bin\
C:\Users\user\Downloads\mymod
\out\production\mymod.main\assets\modid\icon.png
```

I have **no idea** what is going on or where to look to fix this problem...
Im trying to make some fabric mods for minecraft.
This is my [mod on github](https://github.com/Blaze0111/mymod/tree/main/fabric-example-mod-1.18%20-%20Copy) and i have done nothing but follow [this tutorial](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:setup)
Im making this in intellij idea 2022 for Minecraft V1.18.2.
*Plz hlp*

Comment: Someone is trying to use your absolute path name as a relative path.  Do you see it have `...\jbr\bin\C:\Users\user\...`.  Is that in a configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your output directory is not correct.**

In Windows, there is only one : allowed after specifying the drive letter. Your path

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2\jbr\bin\C:\Users\user\Downloads\mymod\out\production\mymod.main\assets\modid\icon.png
```

specifies the path starting from the drive letter (the C drive) twice.

Redo the *optional, but recommended* step of setting the output directory and make sure the path is valid.